# R finding data in table for conditional vector

Tags: r, dataframe

I ran into an issue where I would appreciate some help.
I am looking for a generalized solution that allows me to find the following values of the next e.g. 2 rows in a dataset. Currently my code is:

```
a <- c(9,5,2,5,7)
b <-c(12,4,8,13,10)
c <- c(4,1,9,9,3)
d <-c(8,3,15,2,7)

a1 <- cbind(a,b,c,d)

#vectorquantiles being the condition that needs to be met to then find the values of the next e.g. 2 rows in the original dataset

vectorquantiles <- rowQuantiles(a1, probs = .8, na.rm = TRUE)
a1 <- as.data.frame(a1)
for(j in 1:ncol(a1)){
  s <- set(a1, i=which(a1[[j]] <= vectorquantiles), j=j, value=NA)  
}
```

the final dataset should look like this:

| a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NA | NA | NA | NA |
| NA | 4 | NA | NA |
| 2 | 8 | NA | NA |
| 5 | NA | NA | 2 |
| NA | 10 | NA | 7 |

basically for every value in `s` I want the next 2 rows from the column where the value was found in the original dataset `a1` .
My dataset is much larger in width and length therefore a gernalized solution is necessary.

I hope I was able to make this somewhat clear. This is my first question asked here so and I did not find it easy to formulate my issue.

I appreciate any help.

*alternative ways of solving this are appreciated too

Comment: What packages are you using? `rowQuantiles` is not a base R function.

Comment: I believe its matrixStats